# Get the maximum distance between two consecutive points in a linestring

Tags: postgis, distance

I want to check if a track is valid by measuring the distance between each consecutive points of my track and discarding the tracks which have two consecutive points really far away. My tracks are stored in a linestring. Do you know if its possible to do that?

**input**: `LINESTRING( P1,P2,P3 .. Pn )` size n

**output**: Max Distance between each consecutive points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
   SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom 
   FROM (SELECT 'LINESTRING(0 0, 0 1, 2 1, 2 4, 3 4)'::geometry AS geom) AS foo
),
T2 AS
( 
   SELECT ST_Distance(geom,lead(geom) OVER()) dist FROM T1
)
SELECT max(dist) FROM T2
```

- `(ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom`

  Split your line into `n` points by using [ST_DumpPoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html)
- `ST_Distance(geom,lead(geom) OVER())`

  Compute the distance between one point and the next one by using the window function [LEAD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html)

The example above will then output `3` since there is a distance of `3` units between `point(2 1)` and `point(2,4)`

**SQL FUNCTION:**

If you need to apply this solution on several line contained in a table, we can use the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_SubpathDistance(
    geom GEOMETRY
)

RETURNS FLOAT AS

$BODY$

WITH T1 AS
(
   SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom 
),
T2 AS
( 
   SELECT ST_Distance(geom,lead(geom) OVER()) dist FROM T1
)
SELECT max(dist) FROM T2

$BODY$

LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And then simply use:

```
SELECT ST_SubpathDistance(the_geom), * FROM MyLines
```

Comment: thanks works good, hope its not too expensive on big table ><